# Map /src to /home/vagrant

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I have written a Vagrantfile and would like to sync the /src folder that's in the same root as the Vagrantfile to /home/vagrant.. so that when I vagrant ssh it loads the files in this /src directory.

How do I do this?

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# All Vagrant configuration is done below. The "2" in Vagrant.configure
# configures the configuration version (we support older styles for
# backwards compatibility). Please don't change it unless you know what
# you're doing.
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "bento/ubuntu-18.04"
  # config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 6379, host: 6379
  config.vm.hostname = "geniusbox"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = "1024"
  end
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "init.sh"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend to map to `/home/vagrant` directly, this folder needs to contain your bash files, ssh keys etc, so unless you're sure and you keep all those hidden files/folders on your host you can do it, but otherwise it will lead to issue.

It might be better to map with `/home/vagrant/src` only like

```
config.vm.synced_folder "src/", "/home/vagrant/src"
```